# Receiving texts from different numbers through Python script

Tags: python, windows-phone-7, sms

I have written a simple test script to send an SMS to my smartphone.

```
import smtplib

from_addr = "..."
password = "..."
to_addr = "..."

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(from_addr, password)

for i in range(3):
     server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, "test message")
```

Now, this works fine.  However, I receive three separate texts from numbers 4180, 4176 and 4195.  Is there a way to receive the three texts from one number so that it appears as one conversation on my smartphone? (I have a Windows Phone, btw).  How are these numbers assigned?  Is it something that I can control on my end or is it randomly determined by my phone carrier's SMS gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script does not send texts, it sends mail messages. What SMS shortcodes the resulting texts appear to come from is iindeed controlled *entirely* by the mail-to-SMS gateway run by your mobile phone provider. Presumably your carrier uses multiple gateways assigned in a round-robin fashion.

A workaround might be to add all those shortcodes as alternate numbers for a single contact. Your phone's text app might then group them together. (It might not; I don't have a Windows phone to check.) You could also try a bulk SMS gateway provider like [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/clickatell-products/online-products/sms-gateway-developers-central/) (I just picked them because they have what looks like a wide variety of API support; I have no experience with them and do not endorse them in particular).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.  As a follow-up question, you pointed out that my script sends mail, not SMS.  If my "TO" address happens to be the by provider's SMS gateway, then it appears as an SMS.  Now, is there a way to use Python to actually send SMS instead of mail, posing as SMS?

Comment: Not directly; you have to either run your own gateway software hooked up to the phone network, or you have to use someone else's (which they will probably want you to pay for). Several of the APIs offered by Clickatell (e.g. the HTTP, SOAP, or XML ones) could be used easily from Python.